# make python3.5 as default in AWS?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, pip, default

Is there a way to make python3.5 as the default python in AWS. 
every time i try the next time i connect python2.7 is the default one and pip 6 is the last version, knowing that I did updated it some minutes before.
here is the method i followed : [amazon_link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/cli/latest/userguide/awscli-install-linux.html)

here is another link of amazon telling the versions, actually they are at 3.5 [another_link](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/amazon-linux-ami/2015.03-release-notes/)

Thank you in advance, :)
best wishes

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`alternatives --set python /usr/bin/python3.5`

and then back if you want to

`alternatives --set python /usr/bin/python2.7`

If you want to see what it currently points to

`alternatives --display python`

This is a system-wide setting not just for the current user. The system settings are stored in `/etc/alternatives`

Comment: `# alternatives -h`  `alternatives version 1.3.49.3 - Copyright (C) 2001 Red Hat, Inc.
This may be freely redistributed under the terms of the GNU Public License.`  `# uname -a`  
`Linux hostname 4.14.109-80.92.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Apr 1 23:07:39 UTC 2019 x86_64`x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`  ` yum whatprovides $(which alternatives)
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
chkconfig-1.3.49.3-2.14.amzn1.x86_64 : A system tool for maintaining the /etc/rc*.d hierarchy
Repo        : amzn-main
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/sbin/alternatives`

Answer (score 13):

A simple safe way would be to use an `alias`. Place this into `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_aliases` file:

> alias python=python3

```
Example
$ python --version
Python 2.7.6
$ python3 --version
Python 3.4.3
$ alias python=python3
$ python --version
Python 3.4.3
```

Comment: Yes I did, but when i deconnect and then reconnect, python will be 2.7 by default and pip 6 ;
i left them python 3.5 and pip 9

Comment: I am using EC2 free linux ami, if that can change something!

Comment: This approach can generate even more confusion. Because pip will continue to install your dependencies under python2.7.

Comment: then you should install with pip3 not pip

Answer (score 3):

I used alias and it works for me. (AMI2 AWS)

```
alias python=python3
```

Add this command in `.bashrc`  file and then reboot the server

```
python --version
```

It will show python version 3

Answer (score 1):

By default, the awscli-bundle install script runs under the system default version of Python. To answer your question you will need to know the path of Python version to use.
Then run:

```
$ sudo /path/to/python/version awscli-bundle/install -i /usr/local/aws -b /usr/local/bin/aws
```

In my case I would run:

```
$ sudo /usr/local/bin/python3.7 awscli-bundle/install -i /usr/local/aws -b /usr/local/bin/aws
```

Answer (score 1):

**To change Python Version 3.x**

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.x 1
```

*** Because sometimes priority is required use, you just add '1' at end of command line.**

**To check update**

```
 sudo update-alternatives --list | grep python
```

**Reset Python old version**'

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2.7 1
```

**Just close terminal and restart.**

```
Python -V
3.x
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

do above: `alias python=python36` in  ~.bashrc file (Use emacs, vim, your favorite editor - `emacs ~.bashrc`) then save file.

then in command line terminal type: `source ~/.bashrc` (for changes to take effect)

Answer (score 0):

Because AL2 is picky, unfortunately **NONE** of these answers is *exactly* correct. Here's what worked for me just now (***as root***)-

```
alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2.7 1
alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.7 2
```

3.7 SHOULD be the default now, and you can test with `python --version`.

To change the default at any time:

```
update-alternatives --config python
```

The menu system will prompt you through the change.