# How to check if my EC2 instance have Python3 along with Python2.7? If so how to switch between versions?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have a Python script which accepts yaml script as parameter and validates the set up of DB engines in an environment. This script can be run on Python3 only. But when I connect to my EC2 instance, I see Python2.7 as default. I can't install Python3. Can an instance have 2 different versions of Python? If so, how to switch between versions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [make python3.5 as default in AWS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45220230/make-python3-5-as-default-in-aws)

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't install Python3"? What did you try?

Comment: I do not have the necessary access/privilege to install Python 3.

Comment: You can always use "sudo" for linux or "administrator" for windows.